# How to change a low-res model to high-res while rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

did you know how to change a low-res model of an object (fe. 3d scan) with an high-res model while you hit render?
I would like to replace some UV Spheres with 3D scanned lemons in my scene but that takes ages to import.

Thank you.